# LINQ for grabbing Tuple values and aggregating, etc. into new tuple?

Tags: c#, linq

Got a small problem, as im refactoring my tuple into a new tuple, im getting scared when refactoring all the items, i want to add to my new tuple: sum of what's not 'b', then 'b', then repeat till the list ends, problem is, i dont want to use loops but now I'm humbled and I am open to loop recommendations, but still, is there a linq way to do this easier? and I hear aggregate is something I can use perhaps
example code:

```
var newList = new List<Tuple<char, decimal>>();

newList.Add(new Tuple<char, decimal>('q', .3M));
newList.Add(new Tuple<char, decimal>('w', .4M));
//.7
newList.Add(new Tuple<char, decimal>('b', 1.2M));
//1.2
newList.Add(new Tuple<char, decimal>('r', .3M));
newList.Add(new Tuple<char, decimal>('e', .8M));
//1.1
newList.Add(new Tuple<char, decimal>('b', 1.2M));
//1.2
newList.Add(new Tuple<char, decimal>('b', 1.2M));
//1.2
newList.Add(new Tuple<char, decimal>('b', 1.2M));
//1.2

var refactoredList = new List<Tuple<char, decimal>>();

refactoredList.Add(
    new Tuple<char, decimal>(
        's', 
        newList.TakeWhile(x => x.Item1 != 'b').Sum(x => x.Item2)));
refactoredList.Add(
    new Tuple<char, decimal>(
        'b', 
        newList.Where(x => x.Item1 == 'b').Select(x => x.Item2).First()));
```

Comment: FYI you can use `Tuple.Create` instead of the `Tuple` constructor and you won't have to specify the types.

Comment: huh, been using 'new' forever haha didn't know of .create, thanks

Comment: `i dont want to use loops` What is with the recent loop-o-phobia? There is *nothing* wrong with loops. Using LINQ just means the loop is done behind the scenes. Explicitly trying to re-write a solution to LINQ (especially if you don't know how to do it) means the code becomes more complicated and harder to read than it should be.

Comment: That's not what refactoring means. You are.. converting? aggregating?

Comment: ive been humbled, what are your loop ideas? I just want help with this

Comment: I'd also avoid using Tuple in C# if possible. Properties named Item1, Item2, etc make the code extremely difficult to read. Alternatives are to create a deducted Class or Struct, or use an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean, but here's a sample code that gives you two groups of tuples

```
        var sumOfB = newList
            .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
            .Where(g => g.Key == 'b')
            .Select(s => Tuple.Create('b', s.Sum(t=> t.Item2)));

        var sumOfNotB = newList
            .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
            .Where(g => g.Key != 'b')
            .Select(s => Tuple.Create('s', s.Sum(t => t.Item2)));
```

[image: LinqPad Result]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're doing.  Looks like you're getting the sum of consecutive `b` and non-`b` values.  Write a generator.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<char, decimal>> AggregateGroups(IEnumerable<Tuple<char, decimal>> data)
{
    var state = default(char?);
    var sum = 0M;
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if (state != null && state.Value == 'b' ^ item.Item1 == 'b')
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(state.Value, sum);
            sum = 0M;
        }
        state = item.Item1 == 'b' ? 'b' : 's';
        sum += item.Item2;
    }
    if (state != null)
        yield return Tuple.Create(state.Value, sum);
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var data = new[]
{
    Tuple.Create('q', .3M),
    Tuple.Create('w', .4M),
    //.7
    Tuple.Create('b', 1.2M),
    //1.2
    Tuple.Create('r', .3M),
    Tuple.Create('e', .8M),
    //1.1
    Tuple.Create('b', 1.2M),
    //1.2
    Tuple.Create('b', 1.2M),
    //1.2
    Tuple.Create('b', 1.2M),
};
var result = AggregateGroups(data).ToList();
```

This results in the list:

```
(s, 0.7)
(b, 1.2)
(s, 1.1)
(b, 3.6)
```