# C# Looping through Dictionary and summing values for Keys

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<string, decimal?>`, and i would like to be able to sum the decimals by distinct string. So say i have the below inputs in dictionary,

"1", 20.00
"1", 35.00
"2", 10.00
"3", 15.00
"3", 30.00

I would like the following output to a new Dictionary

"1", 55.00
"2", 10.00
"3", 45.00

I'm guessing it would be something like

```
foreach(var item in dictionary)
{
newDictionary.Add(not sure what would go here, maybe some sort of linq query for distinct and sum?);
}
```

Comment: Dictionaries must have unique keys. e.g. `{ { "1", 20.00 }, { "1", 35.00 } }` is not going to be possible

Comment: would i be able to do it when adding inputs to the first dictionary

Comment: Sure, `dict["1"] = 20.00; dict["1"] += 35.00` works just fine. At no point would you have two values with the same key, you're just updating the value of the existing key.

Comment: I would first investigate what kind of collection you need. A dictionary is not going to work as input, as output it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in a dictionary can't be repeated, so the 2 first entries won't fit in a dictionary.

I think you may have a list of objects that you can loop, then you can use a dictionary to store the total for each "key"

something like

```
 Dictionary<string, double> totals = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        List<Tuple<string, double>> entries = new List<Tuple<string, double>>() {
            new Tuple<string, double>("1",20.00),
            new Tuple<string, double>("1",35.00),
            new Tuple<string, double>("2",10.00),
            new Tuple<string, double>("3",15.00),
            new Tuple<string, double>("3",30.00)
        };
        foreach (var e in entries)
        {
            if (!totals.Keys.Contains(e.Item1))
            {
                totals[e.Item1] = 0;
            }
            totals[e.Item1] += e.Item2;
        }
```

Comment: If Tuples are used, some of the information in this post may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756958/linq-for-grabbing-tuple-values-and-aggregating-etc-into-new-tuple

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the same List of key value pairs as in the other answers:

```
var myList = New List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>> {
    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>("1", (decimal)10.00),
    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>("1", (decimal)15.00),
    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>("2", (decimal)20.00),
    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>("3", (decimal)30.50),
    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>("3", (decimal)17.500)
};

var myResults = myList.GroupBy(p => p.Key)
                      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g=>g.Sum(p=>p.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have Dictionary object with duplicate keys. You would see ArgumentException when you try to add an existing key into the Dictionary object.
Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here You can't use Dictionary if you are using same keys, because they must be Unique. 
You can use list of KeyPair though, which is closest to Dictionary, then you're code will look like this:

```
        List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>>();

        myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>("1", (decimal)10.00));
        myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>("1", (decimal)15.00));
        myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>("3", (decimal)30.50));
        myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal?>("3", (decimal)17.500));

        Dictionary<string, decimal?> sums = new Dictionary<string, decimal?>(); //This can be a dictionary because the keys will be unique after grouping 

        foreach (var item in myList.GroupBy(m => m.Key))
        {
            string currentKey = item.FirstOrDefault().Key;
            sums.Add(currentKey, myList.Where(j => j.Key == currentKey).Sum(o => o.Value));
        }
```

Comment: GroupBy already does all your grouping for you (hence its name). Each group in your collection of groups has a Key (no need to do firstOrDefault), and is already a collection of the KeyValuePairs matching that key. so you can just sum off it directly without needing to query back to the original list repeatedly.
See my answer.